# Keras plot_model doesn't work, despite importing pydot and graphviz

Tags: python, tf.keras

I've already downloaded and imported pydot and graphviz in the notebook where I want to plot the keras model.

```
pydot.__version__
'1.4.2'

graphviz.__version__
'0.17'
```

However, when I run `keras.utils.plot_model(model_func,show_shapes=True)`, where model_func is the name of model I want to plot, returns

```
('You must install pydot (`pip install pydot`) and install graphviz (see instructions at https://graphviz.gitlab.io/download/) ', 'for plot_model/model_to_dot to work.')
```

Why is this?

Comment: This seems to be a common problem - a search of stackoverflow will provide many examples.  Though the documentation implies that you installed Graphviz, you really only installed an interface to Graphviz.  You still need to install Graphviz itself.

Comment: @sroush Can you suggest how to do that?

Comment: OS dependent, but start here: https://graphviz.org/download/